# ava watch functionality and transpiling typescript

Tags: typescript, ava

Is it possible to use ava --watch functionality when i write the tests in typescript?

Now I have something like this

```
"test": "tsc -p tsconfig.test.json && ava \"dist_test/**/*.js\""
```

Only it would be nice to have it only test modified source / test files during development.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [chokidar-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar-cli) to detect the file changes and get it to manually run the build and test.

```
"test": "tsc -p tsconfig.test.json && ava \"dist_test/**/*.js\"",
"test:watch": "chokidar \"dist_test/**/*.js\" -c \"npm run test\" --initial",
```

Once changes are detected in any files it will run `test` for you.